# Iteration of Items in Jubula

Tags: loops, jubula

I would like to repeat a Test Case in a loop and access an increasing counter in the repeated case.

Is there any way to do this in Jubula?

I created a Repeat loop in a Test Case to loop some Test Steps, there is a table whose row should be iterated by one each time.

[It looks a bit like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bK7K.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the variable. `b`

Set the variable to the initial value before your repeat.
`ub_app_storeValue module - VARIABLE_NAME: Counter, Value: 1`

Then apply the value of variable `$Counter` in your ROW parameter.

Add the `increment` command at the end of your repeat loop.
`ub_app_storeValue module - VARIABLE_NAME: Counter, Value:?add($Counter,1)`

Milos

Answer (score 0):

There's no "repeat" Test case in Jubula.

But you can achieve iteration with Data Sets; create a dummy Excel Data file with as many rows as many times you want the test-case to be repeated. Then associate it to your Test Case in the Properties view.

You can create a column with increasing numbers in it and access it in your Test Case, this way it will function as a counter.

Comment: I now use the Central Test Data for the loop and as an iterator, but I want to iterate the number for each loop pass. This does not work because I write the iterations to a new row in the Central Test Data. 
Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean exactly. Could you edit your question to include an example of how you want your numbers to change between iterations?

Comment: i changed the Question and added a picture, i hope it's more understandable now